# Wrapping XLOPER/XLOPER12 from Excel C Api in c# (with excel-dna ?)

Tags: c#, excel-dna, xll

I have a huge XLL (more than a hundred of functions) coded (in C) using the [Excel C API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/programming-with-the-c-api-in-excel).

I need to use several functions of this XLL in a C# code.

The code of these functions is quite an intricate numerical code that I wrote during several months, several years ago, fairly tested, backtested and validated, so that I am not at all into recoding into C# these C functions.

Each function of the XLL has all its input parameters of one single type `XLOPER *` and returns a `LPXLOPER`, where for the sake of completion, we have :

```
typedef struct xloper
{
    union
    {
        double num;                 /* xltypeNum */
        LPSTR str;                  /* xltypeStr */
#ifdef __cplusplus
        WORD xbool;                 /* xltypeBool */
#else   
        WORD bool;                  /* xltypeBool */
#endif  
        WORD err;                   /* xltypeErr */
        short int w;                    /* xltypeInt */
        struct
        {
            WORD count;             /* always = 1 */
            XLREF ref;
        } sref;                     /* xltypeSRef */
        struct
        {
            XLMREF *lpmref;
            IDSHEET idSheet;
        } mref;                     /* xltypeRef */
        struct
        {
            struct xloper *lparray;
            WORD rows;
            WORD columns;
        } array;                    /* xltypeMulti */
        struct
        {
            union
            {
                short int level;        /* xlflowRestart */
                short int tbctrl;       /* xlflowPause */
                IDSHEET idSheet;        /* xlflowGoto */
            } valflow;
            WORD rw;                /* xlflowGoto */
            BYTE col;               /* xlflowGoto */
            BYTE xlflow;
        } flow;                     /* xltypeFlow */
        struct
        {
            union
            {
                BYTE *lpbData;          /* data passed to XL */
                HANDLE hdata;           /* data returned from XL */
            } h;
            long cbData;
        } bigdata;                  /* xltypeBigData */
    } val;
    WORD xltype;
} XLOPER, *LPXLOPER;
```

(definition in the `XLCALL.h` file of the Excal C API.)

Each function `F` of the XLL takes parameters of the type `XLOPER*` and, according to what these paramters should represent, performs various checks on the parameters etc etc, to finally construct objects of various custom structs types, that are finally passed to an underlying C function `f` whose parameters are native C types or complicated stackings of structs and native types etc.

Marshalling theses structs (and structs of structs, structs of structs of ... of structs) would be an endless task. (And yes, it was and still is bad design to have so tightly coupled the "pure" C code to the Excel API C code ...)

This is why I want to marshall the `XLOPER *`, `LPXLOPER` and any types using to define them. An XLL being after all a DLL, It should be possible. (I have still a doubt about the XLL needing or not to be aware of the context of Excel using it, which could stop its use from a c# code ...)

I found code doing parts of this marshalling here :

https://www.demo2s.com/csharp/csharp-icustommarshaler-marshalnativetomanaged-intptr-pnativedata.html

and the namespace it lives in suggests it is a part of Excel DNA, yet I have not succeed in finding that code in the [Excel-Dna GitHub repository](https://github.com/Excel-DNA), where I found traces of marshalling code, but only in internal classes, so that I am stuck.

(Naturally Excel-DNA hides all of this as it target is especially to alleviate the user from meddling with the Excel C Api but, as I am not an Excel-Dna expert, maybe Excel-Dna allows for such a marshalling.)

Comment: It might be simpler to write new wrapper methods in C that are simple to call from C# with P/Invoke or COM interop.

Comment: Given that I precise in my question that the XLL functions are tightly coupled to their underlying pure C functions and that marshalling the return/input types of these pure C functions would be a nightmare, I don't understand what these wrapper methods would do ? I mean they would at least need to understand and simplify what `XLOPER`s etc are, which should as difficult as marshlling directly them to C#, isn't it ?

Comment: Excel-DNA has enough code to make the marshalling quite easy, though the Excel xll memory model is a bit clumsy. Also, your add-in likely makes calls back to Excel using the C API, even if it is just for type conversions, so you might have to fake some of this. I'd be happy to point you to the right code and help you get started - you can get my email from the Excel-DNA GitHub account.

Comment: Hi Govert ! I will send you an email, thank you !